# How to manage functions that are in multiple modules when one is unknown

Tags: perl

I'm attempting to edit a script in Lava (Perl language that has been extended for use in the mining software Vulcan).

I've run into an issue with modules and as I'm not used to Perl I haven't been able to solve it completely.

A snippet of the code is below

The module that is causing issues is "Macro".

```
use Lava;
use warnings;
use strict;
use vulcan;
use utf8;
use Macro 'RunMenu';
use File::Basename;

my $tri = 'C:\\_PROJECTS\\1404134_abc\\VULCAN\\faults.tri\\retriangulated\\gbc_ne1e_1606.00t';
my $tr = new Triangulation($tri);

#Runs fine
RunMenu("TRI_UTE_LOAD:$tri","abort",
      "FINISH") || die "Macro mismatch.\n";

#Does not run fine
RunMenu("TRI_EDIT_INTERP","abort",
      sub { Triangulation("$basedir\\$tri"); },

      sub { PanelResults("Select interpolation option",
                "line" => "",
                "Maximum triangle area  " => "$maxTriArea",
                "Maximum boundary length" => "100.0",
                "button_pressed" => "ok",
                "Interpolate midpoints" => "1",
                "Interpolate centroids" => "0",
                "Honour breaklines" => "1"
                   ); },
      "FINISH") || die "Macro mismatch.\n";
```

If I omit `use Macro;` this line `my $tr = new Triangulation($tri);` runs fine but then I can't use the `RunMenu` command.

If I include `use Macro;` I get `Bareword found where operator expected at C:\_PROJECTS\1404134_abc\VULCAN\new.lava line 12, near "new Triangulation"
    (Do you need to predeclare new?)`

The closest I've got is `use Macro 'RunMenu';` but then I get `Undefined subroutine &main::Triangulation called at C:\_PROJECTS\1404134_abc\VULCAN\test4.lava line 45.`

What I believe is happening is `Macro` contains a function `triangulation` which is overwriting one in some other module (Don't know which module it is in or how to find out, I tried commenting out the other ones I load and it ran fine without all of them).

Any suggestions on how to use the two different triangulation functions when I don't know where one comes from?  Or if anyone can suggest any other fixes it would be much appreciated.

The code is being run through Vulcan so I'm not sure which Perl debugging tools I can use.

### Edit:

I've copied the help file below if your interested
[Help file](http://pastebin.com/VtmJNTxx)

The most useful part was here

**Triangulation Class**

The Triangulation object provides an interface to the Envisage triangulation structures. The point and triangle data may be accessed through the member functions.

Each triangle consists of 3 vertex indices. These are indices into the point array, which holds a 3D location for each point. The triangles are formed by using the three sets of 3D points as vertices.

Methods:
$triangulation = new Triangulation($name)

```
$triangulation : Returned triangulation object.
$name          : Optional triangulation name.
```

The constructor returns a new triangulation object. If a name is provided then the triangulation of the given name is loaded.

$result = is_valid

```
$result : Whether a triangulation has been successfully loaded or set.
```

$points = points

```
$points : The number of points in the triangulation
```

$triangles = triangles

```
$triangles : Number of triangles in the object
```

Comment: Inspect the [`%INC hash`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables), a list of loaded modules (name.pm => location, full path). You can also grep all those files for `sub [Tt]riangulation` or such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems Triangulation is a class and function name at the same time. Perl doesn't know which one you want to use, but you can help it by using parentheses after function calls, you should also avoid "indirect object" syntax for methods, and possibly quote the class names or append `::` to them:

```
my $tr = 'Triangulation'->new($tri);
# or
my $tr = Triangulation::->new($tri);
```

avoid:

```
my $tr = new Triangulation($tri);
Triangulation "$basedir\\$tri";
```

Comment: I got to wondering if the call to `new()` should be omitted entirely, and just called like `my $tr = Triangulation($tri);` instead. It's pretty confusing as to what's happening behind the scenes

Comment: @stevieb: It's not the same. One calls Triangulation function, the other a constructor of the Triangulation class. Unless there's a `new` function, not a method, which I don't know, as I don't see the source of Lava.

Comment: Using your method it gets past that error.  Now I'm getting another error.  I've updated the code above to include the error (I guess it wasn't getting to that point before).  I've also included the help file for lava if you want but the new was being used as a constructor. `Can't locate object method "points" via package "TRIANGULATION_OK" (perhaps you forgot to load "TRIANGULATION_OK"?) at C:\_PROJECTS\1404134_abc\VULCAN\test4.lava line 137.`

Comment: @gtwebb I think you forgot to edit your code in the question; it's still the same as in the original version. But you shouldn't change questions significantly after you get answers, anyway. I would post a new question.